# Load data using pickle from 2 different class

Tags: python, nltk, pickle

I am new to python and i learned about pickle to pass data between classes. I have 2 different class, the first one is classifier class where i want to train and classify all my data set. The data set is quite large which contains 50k of tweets and I classify using nltk naive bayes classsifier. I have another data from different class that i pickle and i want to load it in the same class.

I had try to load data from other class into the classifier class. Then i pickle all the data together with the classifier. I manage to do this but I want to avoid having to classify my data set every time I run my system.

This is how I load data from the other class and pickle it back together with the classifier.

```
#This is the snipped coding in my first class
k = open('key_word1.pickle','wb')
pickle.dump(key_word,k)
pickle.dump(final,k)
#print(key_word)
k.close()



#This is snipped coding in my second class
import pickle
j = open('key_word1.pickle','rb')
key_word = pickle.load(j)
final = pickle.load(j)
#print(key_word)
#print(final)
j.close()

f = open('data.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(featureList, f)
pickle.dump(classifier, f)
pickle.dump(key_word, f)
pickle.dump(final, f)
#print(classifier)
f.close()

#this is snipped coding in my third class
#i load pickle from second class that have combine with first class pickle
f = open('data.pickle', 'rb')
featureList = pickle.load(f)
data = pickle.load(f)
key_word = pickle.load(f)
final = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Can I do something like this instead to avoid my data having to go through the second class every time I run my system? I have try it and i think can only load from one pickle at a time and the other load pickle will be ignored. Or maybe I done something wrong in my coding.

```
#I try to load from first class and second class at the same time

import pickle
j = open('key_word1.pickle','rb')
key_word = pickle.load(j)
final = pickle.load(j)
#print(key_word)
#print(final)
j.close()


f = open('data.pickle', 'rb')
featureList = pickle.load(f)
data = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: I advice you to use cPickle instead. You can just "import cPickle as pickle". Then, I also advice to use separate files for each class, or store them into a dictionary which you will pickle. Once they are loaded separately they are references and you can do whatever you want with them very fast. Your question is a little bit vague, so please clarify a bit more.

Comment: act the coding in my question is not from the same file. I pick snipped code from them and combine to show the pickle and load data. I have 2 file that I use pickle. I want to load from the 2 file simultaneously in another as in my second part of coding. Did i clarify what im trying to do with this?

Comment: Maybe you can call pickle.load() on same file multiple times, but then the mode for writing file in which you will dump have to be "wb+", not "wb". Even if pickle does not object to multiple loads, I stil don't really get what do you wish to achieve with this.

Comment: This code loads twice from same file, and dums twice into same file. I just realized, "wb+" was a mistake, if you are doing it at the same time. Sorry. My brain is fuzzy. But, this will not intersect your classes if this is what you want. Anyway, when you say class, you mean object or real class?

Comment: what i mean is act class not object. In my code you can l see I try to open two different pickle which come from different class. First is 'testClassify.pickle' and the second is 'data.pickle'. So my question is can I open and load different pickle data coming from different class. Im doing this in another different class, a new class to test classify. So, that's why i just load the pickle in the second part of the coding in my question.

Comment: Then you have a problem. You cannot pickle classes or functions.
Pickle is a serialized shallow copy of an object or data structure.
Instantiate your classes, do some magic with those objects, pickle/unpickle them, and you will be fine.

Comment: ¸When you pickle class or function, you get just a note to use class which must already exist as such. When you pickle an object, you get a note to use class which must already exist as a template, it gets instantiated and filled with data stored in a pickle.
Did you saw your dumped files? If you're trying to store a class in them, they'll be just one line. Or Python 3 knows some more pickling magic than 2.

Comment: I did not store class in the pickle. featureList and final are a list, classifier is an object, key_word is a String data type data. I did not get any error when I try to pickle from 2 different class, just that the second time I try open and load different pickle. I cant obtained the data. So from your opinion, I can load from 2 different pickle at the same time if the data type is right?

Comment: As I said, dumping more objects (never mind which) in series to the same file might work in theory, loading as well. Maybe not just like you imagined (directly), perhaps you will have to know some dirty tricks to fool the picle module. The thing is that each dump produces completely new pickle. I will try it tonight and let you know.

Comment: But in the general, the answer is no. You pickle each object in a new file, and load each from different files. Or you put all you want to pickle inside a dictionary and pickle it. When you unpickle, you get the dictionary with all objects at the same time. Then, you take from it all you need, and put data where you need.

Comment: Or you use pickle.loads() and pickle.dumps() to get your objects pickled as strings and then construct your output file as you wish, so that you can store multiple pickles and load them from it. You can do wanders. Eg. store your pickles in a ZIP archive. They will be on the same place if that is what you want.
There is definitely no need to classify all dataon on every run.